# Add padding to live engraved text on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm working on a solution for live engraving text on a bracelet, using a canvas overlay.

My fiddle is here:

```js
var first = true;
startIt();


function startIt()
{
    canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
    canvasDiv.innerHTML = '<canvas id="layer0" width="400" height="400"></canvas>'; //for IE
    canvas = document.getElementById('layer0');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
    curve = document.getElementById('curve');
    curveText = document.getElementById('text');
    $(curve).keyup(function(e) {changeCurve();});
    $(curveText).keyup(function(e) {changeCurve();});
    
    
    
       
    if (first)
    {
        changeCurve();
        first = false;
    }
    
}

function changeCurve()
{
points = curve.value.split(',');  
    if (points.length == 8)
        drawStack();
  
}

function drawStack()
{
    Ribbon = {maxChar: 50, startX: points[0], startY: points[1], 
              control1X: points[2], control1Y: points[3], 
              control2X: points[4], control2Y: points[5], 
              endX: points[6], endY: points[7]};
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    ctx.moveTo(Ribbon.startX,Ribbon.startY);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(Ribbon.control1X,Ribbon.control1Y,
                   Ribbon.control2X,Ribbon.control2Y,
                   Ribbon.endX,Ribbon.endY);
    
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
   FillRibbon(curveText.value,Ribbon); 
}

function FillRibbon(text,Ribbon)
{

var textCurve = [];
var ribbon = text.substring(0,Ribbon.maxChar);
var curveSample = 1000;


xDist = 0;
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < curveSample; i++)
    {
        a = new bezier2(i/curveSample,Ribbon.startX,Ribbon.startY,Ribbon.control1X,Ribbon.control1Y,Ribbon.control2X,Ribbon.control2Y,Ribbon.endX,Ribbon.endY);
        b = new bezier2((i+1)/curveSample,Ribbon.startX,Ribbon.startY,Ribbon.control1X,Ribbon.control1Y,Ribbon.control2X,Ribbon.control2Y,Ribbon.endX,Ribbon.endY);
        c = new bezier(a,b);
        textCurve.push({bezier: a, curve: c.curve});
    }

letterPadding = ctx.measureText("").width / 4; 
w = ribbon.length;
ww = Math.round(ctx.measureText(ribbon).width);


totalPadding = (w-1) * letterPadding;
totalLength = ww + totalPadding;
p = 0;

cDist = textCurve[curveSample-1].curve.cDist;

z = (cDist / 2) - (totalLength / 2);

for (i=0;i<curveSample;i++)
    {
        if (textCurve[i].curve.cDist >= z)
        {
            p = i;
            break;
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < w ; i++)
    {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(textCurve[p].bezier.point.x,textCurve[p].bezier.point.y);
        ctx.rotate(textCurve[p].curve.rad);
        ctx.fillText(ribbon[i],0,0);
        ctx.restore();
        
        x1 = ctx.measureText(ribbon[i]).width + letterPadding;
        x2 = 0; 
        for (j=p;j<curveSample;j++)
        {
        x2 = x2 + textCurve[j].curve.dist;
        if (x2 >= x1)
            {
                p = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        



    }
} //end FillRibon

function bezier(b1, b2)
{
//Final stage which takes p, p+1 and calculates the rotation, distance on the path and accumulates the total distance
this.rad = Math.atan(b1.point.mY/b1.point.mX);
this.b2 = b2;
this.b1 = b1;
dx = (b2.x - b1.x);
dx2 = (b2.x - b1.x) * (b2.x - b1.x);
this.dist = Math.sqrt( ((b2.x - b1.x) * (b2.x - b1.x)) + ((b2.y - b1.y) * (b2.y - b1.y)) );
xDist = xDist + this.dist;
this.curve = {rad: this.rad, dist: this.dist, cDist: xDist};
}

function bezierT(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY)
{
//calculates the tangent line to a point in the curve; later used to calculate the degrees of rotation at this point.
this.mx = (3*(1-t)*(1-t) * (control1X - startX)) + ((6 * (1-t) * t) * (control2X - control1X)) + (3 * t * t * (endX - control2X));
this.my = (3*(1-t)*(1-t) * (control1Y - startY)) + ((6 * (1-t) * t) * (control2Y - control1Y)) + (3 * t * t * (endY - control2Y));
}

function bezier2(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY)
{
//Quadratic bezier curve plotter
this.Bezier1 = new bezier1(t,startX,startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y);
this.Bezier2 = new bezier1(t,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY);
this.x = ((1 - t) * this.Bezier1.x) + (t * this.Bezier2.x);
this.y = ((1 - t) * this.Bezier1.y) + (t * this.Bezier2.y);
this.slope = new bezierT(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY);

this.point = {t: t, x: this.x, y: this.y, mX: this.slope.mx, mY: this.slope.my};
}
function bezier1(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y)
{
//linear bezier curve plotter; used recursivly in the quadratic bezier curve calculation
this.x = (( 1 - t) * (1 - t) * startX) + (2 * (1 - t) * t * control1X) + (t * t * control2X);
this.y = (( 1 - t) * (1 - t) * startY) + (2 * (1 - t) * t * control1Y) + (t * t * control2Y);

}
```

```css
.product-images-container {
  
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px; 
  position:relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.productImage {
  
  width: 100%
  
}
.engravingArea {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-images-container">
    <input size="80" type="text" id="curve" name="curve" value="40,228,100,260,270,260,330,240">
    <input size="80" type="text" id="text" name="text" value="testing 1234567890">
<div class="engravingArea">
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>
</div>
    
<img class="productImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/BaoChJT.jpeg"> 
</div>
```

1. What i wish to achieve, is to centralize the text on the cuff (adding some letter padding to the bottom i suppose?)
2. The text is a little blurry? Is there anyway to optimize it to be better quality?
3. I wish to scale the canvas (and text inside) dynamically when its container resizes as well. The container uses percentage width, and we'd like the canvas to follow the exact measures of either the container or the image itself. I tried setting canvas.width = $(".product-images-container").width(), without luck in this case.

Looking forward to hearing your feedback!

Comment: IMHO in this projection the text should really remain pretty much vertical.   The amount of tilt in towards the center looks unnatural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uajfh78p/

```js
var first = true;

var productImage = document.getElementsByClassName('productImage')[0];
var curveOffset = document.getElementById('offset');
var fontSize = document.getElementById('fontsize');

$(productImage).on('load', function() {
    startIt();
});


function startIt()
{
    canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
    canvasDiv.innerHTML = '<canvas id="layer0" width="' + productImage.naturalWidth + '" height="' + productImage.naturalHeight + '"></canvas>'; //for IE
    canvas = document.getElementById('layer0');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    curve = document.getElementById('curve');
    curveText = document.getElementById('text');
    scale = productImage.naturalWidth/400;
    $(curve).keyup(function(e) {changeCurve();});
    $(curveText).keyup(function(e) {changeCurve();});
    
    
    $(curveOffset).on('change', changeCurve);
    $(fontSize).on('change', changeCurve);
    
       
    if (first)
    {
        changeCurve();
        first = false;
    }
    
}

function changeCurve()
{
points = curve.value.split(',');  
offset = (parseInt(curveOffset.value) || 0);
ctx.font = (parseInt(fontSize.value) || 20)*scale + "px Courier New";

    if (points.length == 8)
        drawStack();
        
    
  
}

function drawStack()
{
    Ribbon = {maxChar: 50, startX: points[0]*scale, startY: (points[1] - offset)*scale, 
              control1X: points[2]*scale, control1Y: (points[3] - offset)*scale, 
              control2X: points[4]*scale, control2Y: (points[5] - offset)*scale, 
              endX: points[6]*scale, endY: (points[7] - offset)*scale};
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    ctx.moveTo(Ribbon.startX,Ribbon.startY);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(Ribbon.control1X,Ribbon.control1Y,
                   Ribbon.control2X,Ribbon.control2Y,
                   Ribbon.endX,Ribbon.endY);
    
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
   FillRibbon(curveText.value,Ribbon); 
}

function FillRibbon(text,Ribbon)
{

var textCurve = [];
var ribbon = text.substring(0,Ribbon.maxChar);
var curveSample = 1000;


xDist = 0;
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < curveSample; i++)
    {
        a = new bezier2(i/curveSample,Ribbon.startX,Ribbon.startY,Ribbon.control1X,Ribbon.control1Y,Ribbon.control2X,Ribbon.control2Y,Ribbon.endX,Ribbon.endY);
        b = new bezier2((i+1)/curveSample,Ribbon.startX,Ribbon.startY,Ribbon.control1X,Ribbon.control1Y,Ribbon.control2X,Ribbon.control2Y,Ribbon.endX,Ribbon.endY);
        c = new bezier(a,b);
        textCurve.push({bezier: a, curve: c.curve});
    }

letterPadding = ctx.measureText("").width / 4; 
w = ribbon.length;
ww = Math.round(ctx.measureText(ribbon).width);


totalPadding = (w-1) * letterPadding;
totalLength = ww + totalPadding;
p = 0;

cDist = textCurve[curveSample-1].curve.cDist;

z = (cDist / 2) - (totalLength / 2);

for (i=0;i<curveSample;i++)
    {
        if (textCurve[i].curve.cDist >= z)
        {
            p = i;
            break;
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < w ; i++)
    {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(textCurve[p].bezier.point.x,textCurve[p].bezier.point.y);
        ctx.rotate(textCurve[p].curve.rad);
        ctx.fillText(ribbon[i],0,0);
        ctx.restore();
        
        x1 = ctx.measureText(ribbon[i]).width + letterPadding;
        x2 = 0; 
        for (j=p;j<curveSample;j++)
        {
        x2 = x2 + textCurve[j].curve.dist;
        if (x2 >= x1)
            {
                p = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        



    }
} //end FillRibon

function bezier(b1, b2)
{
//Final stage which takes p, p+1 and calculates the rotation, distance on the path and accumulates the total distance
this.rad = Math.atan(b1.point.mY/b1.point.mX);
this.b2 = b2;
this.b1 = b1;
dx = (b2.x - b1.x);
dx2 = (b2.x - b1.x) * (b2.x - b1.x);
this.dist = Math.sqrt( ((b2.x - b1.x) * (b2.x - b1.x)) + ((b2.y - b1.y) * (b2.y - b1.y)) );
xDist = xDist + this.dist;
this.curve = {rad: this.rad, dist: this.dist, cDist: xDist};
}

function bezierT(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY)
{
//calculates the tangent line to a point in the curve; later used to calculate the degrees of rotation at this point.
this.mx = (3*(1-t)*(1-t) * (control1X - startX)) + ((6 * (1-t) * t) * (control2X - control1X)) + (3 * t * t * (endX - control2X));
this.my = (3*(1-t)*(1-t) * (control1Y - startY)) + ((6 * (1-t) * t) * (control2Y - control1Y)) + (3 * t * t * (endY - control2Y));
}

function bezier2(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY)
{
//Quadratic bezier curve plotter
this.Bezier1 = new bezier1(t,startX,startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y);
this.Bezier2 = new bezier1(t,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY);
this.x = ((1 - t) * this.Bezier1.x) + (t * this.Bezier2.x);
this.y = ((1 - t) * this.Bezier1.y) + (t * this.Bezier2.y);
this.slope = new bezierT(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y,endX,endY);

this.point = {t: t, x: this.x, y: this.y, mX: this.slope.mx, mY: this.slope.my};
}
function bezier1(t,startX, startY,control1X,control1Y,control2X,control2Y)
{
//linear bezier curve plotter; used recursivly in the quadratic bezier curve calculation
this.x = (( 1 - t) * (1 - t) * startX) + (2 * (1 - t) * t * control1X) + (t * t * control2X);
this.y = (( 1 - t) * (1 - t) * startY) + (2 * (1 - t) * t * control1Y) + (t * t * control2Y);

}
```

```css
.product-images-container {
  
    width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.productImage {
  
  width: 100%
  
}
.engravingArea {
    position: relative;
}

#canvasDiv > canvas {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-images-container">
    <label for="curve">Curve</label><input size="80" type="text" id="curve" name="curve" value="40,228,100,260,270,260,330,240">
    <label for="text">Text</label><input size="80" type="text" id="text" name="text" value="testing 1234567890">
    <label for="offset">Y offset</label><input size="80" type="number" id="offset" name="offset" value="5">
    <label for="fontsize">Font size</label><input size="80" type="number" id="fontsize" name="fontsize" value="20">
<div class="engravingArea">
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>
</div>
    
<img class="productImage" src="https://i.imgur.com/BaoChJT.jpeg"> 
</div>
```

1. I've added a field called offset, which allows you to specify the y offset from the bottom. This value gets incorporated into the curve digits before rendering to the canvas. This, together with a similar field for font size, allows easy adjustment to match the image (`changeCurve()` is called when either is changed).
2. I would recommend making the canvas the same pixel size as the image, so that it will be just as sharp. I've changed the code to read the image width, then create the canvas at that size, using a scaling factor to scale dimensions accordingly.
3. Having resized the canvas in 2., scaling the whole thing simply becomes a case of setting the CSS so that both the canvas and image fill their container width, so that they scale together.

Comment: Hi @sbgib!

Thank you for a great, thorough answer. It worked as expected! On a side note, i have some scripts, that's changing value of the text input programmatically. I tried calling drawStack(); in those functions, but nothing happens and the text doesnt update on the canvas. Should i be calling startIt() instead or?

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it worked :) Without changing anything, if I just try: `setTimeout(updateScript, 500);  function updateScript(){ document.getElementById('text').value = 'changed by script'; drawStack(); }` - that seems to work, but not without `setTimeout`. I had changed the code at the top to wait for the image to load and find out its dimensions - that could be why. Try adding a callback function to tell the next script when this script is ready to receive changes, e.g. `$(productImage).on('load', function() { startIt(); runNextScript(); });` Good luck!

Comment: Hi @sbgip,

I have some additional issues here. First of all, the on load function for the image, doesn't work if the image is cached. This fails the startIt() function to run. 

Also we have a double text input, and an if else statematen, which checks for a specific  class on one of the parents, to toggle between coordinates input fields and text input ( we have 2 set of inputs for coordinates, which reads fine a page load).

The gist includes full canvas code and a snippet of the functions which should trigger a redraw. 

I'll attach relevant links in new comment. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @sbgib Here is the shopify preview link: https://www.customcuff.co/?_ab=0&_fd=0&_sc=1&preview_theme_id=83969376317
To debug go to: Custom Products -> Custom Cuff product. This would have the canvas on it.

The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/Magnuspil/1562c87b3f0babcebcc211524b37d97c

If possible, we could create a stack chat and discuss? I really appreciated the help last time!

Comment: No problem, I created a chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225102/engraved-text-on-canvas), let's see if we can get that fixed :)

Comment: Thank you! I have joined, but I need permission to type ;)

Comment: You should have access now.